# netstat format question on Linux

Tags: networking

Seeing following output to netstat, what do (1)*:*, (2)*:8102, (3)*:ibm-db2 indicate respectively?

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 *:8102                      *:*                         LISTEN 
tcp        0      0 *:ibm-db2                   *:*                         LISTEN
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that an application on your computer is listening on TCP ports 8102 and (I think) 446 or 523, which is the default port for IBM DB2 servers. Listening on a port allows the application to receive connections from other computers over the network.

The Foreign Address column indicates the IP address of who you're connected to. Right now, it appears that you are not connected to anyone which is why `*.*` appears.

Comment: so ibm-db2 here represents a number?

Comment: Yes, the database of known services can be queried with `getent services ibm-db2`

Comment: where does the mapping (maybe in a config file) between ibm-db2 and the port #?

Comment: On linux, it should be located in `/etc/services` I believe

Comment: It may be elsewhere if so configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` -- you should use `getent` to access the `services` database (and other similar databases).

Comment: The `--numeric-ports` argument will make `netstat` print the port number, and not display the port label.